# Get filename from __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just trying to get filename to pass from init, so that I do not have to put for example 'file.txt' in the parameter of the insert function.

```
class Simpledb():
      def __init__(self, filename):
          self.filename = filename

      def insert(self, key, value): 
          f = open(self.filename, 'a+')
          f.write(key + '\t' + value + '\n')
          f.close()
```

When used from another module with code `from database2 import *` and then `Simpledb.insert('database.txt', name, number)`(name and number are input strings), returns "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'". 
How can I insert successfully?

Comment: You need to create an instance or export an instance: `someInstance = Simpledb('filte_name')` and then call `someInstance.insert(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your class in the other code, for example:

```py
from database2 import *

myDB = Simpledb("database.txt")
myDB.insert(name,number)
```